# Consuming Web Service protected by Citrix Access Gateway

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl, citrix

I'm trying to use a web service that is exposed to the outside world via a Citric Access Gateway (CAG) but I'm not sure how to authenticate with the CAG using .net does anyone have any idea how I might go about this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you writing a desktop application? If so, you could potentially follow a similar route to OAuth-style authentication; given a particular HTTP request object pop up a browser window (in-process) pointing at the CAG authentication page that uses this request, the user would then enter their user name and password and the browser would be redirect by the CAG to some sort of welcome URL (prefixed with the CAG-generated hash). Then reuse the HTTP request object (which presumably has some cookie or other auth token associate with it?) in a web service client proxy?